# Using Retrofit @GET with a WeatherAPI - static parameters

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I am using the OpenWeather API and taking my first crack at Retrofit. I am trying to pull the forecast for a period of X number of days. The documentation for a forecast API can be found here:

http://openweathermap.org/forecast16

It looks like the relevant link to the API for a particular city's forecast is below:

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q={city name},{country code}&cnt={cnt}
```

With my base URL being:

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?
```

I am a bit confused about how I meet my @GET annotation and the associated method for an asynchronous response.  The "&" in the API link is confusing as well since I don't really know I would include a static part of the API call in my @GET annotation.  Here is what I have:

```
public interface WeatherAPI {

@GET("/forecast/daily?")
void getResponse(@Query("city")String city, @Query("country_code") int countryCode, @Query("number_of_days") int number_of_days, Callback<List<WeatherForecast>> response);

 }
```

Any help with this specific problem and how to tackle Retrofit in general would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine. Retrofit takes care of the `&` symbol.

```
public interface WeatherAPI {
    @GET("/forecast/daily?")
    void getResponse(
                    @Query("city") String city,
                    @Query("country_code") int countryCode,
                    @Query("number_of_days") int number_of_days,
                    Callback<List<WeatherForecast>> response
    );    
}
```

I have an API endpoint like this:

```
http://myserver.com/api/posts/?page_size=5&page=1
```

And this is my Retrofit interface method:

```
@GET("/posts/")
void getPostPage(
                 @Query("page") int page,
                 @Query("page_size") int pageSize,
                 Callback<PostPage> callback
);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will give it a test and let you know if it works! I am new to programming so Retrofit is a bit advanced, but it seems that it encapsulates a lot of the original AsyncTask class that I had previously read about.