# Android retrofit2.BuiltInConverters$RequestBodyConverter Error

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, openweathermap

I am making a weather application using **retrofit** and **openweather API**.

This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303003/parse-data-from-openweathermap-using-retrofit2-and-rxjava2) is guied me for calling API but I always faced with **retrofit2.BuiltInConverters$RequestBodyConverter** error.

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426600/using-retrofit-get-with-a-weatherapi-static-parameters) but does not work.

My API is here:

`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Ankara&APPID=6a5ea99c096c7ed68e620675d3eb2e2b`

This my gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
```

This is Weather.java:

```
public class Weather {

public int id;
public String main;
public String description;
public String icon;

public Weather(int id, String main, String description, String icon) {
    this.id = id;
    this.main = main;
    this.description = description;
    this.icon = icon;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getMain() {
    return main;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}
```

}

This is ApiClient.java:

```
public class ApiClient {

public static final String BASE_URL = WeatherService.BASE_URL;
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

This is my interface:

```
public interface WeatherService {

//API LINK
String BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5";
String API_KEY = "6a5ea99c096c7ed68e620675d3eb2e2b";

//API SUBCLASS
@GET("/weather?")
//q=CityName &appid =APIKEY
Call<Weather> getWeatherData(@Query("q") String cityName,@Query("appid") String apikey);
```

}

and finally MainActiviy.java:

```
public TextView tv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    //asyncTask.execute(API_KEY);


    WeatherService weatherService = ApiClient.getClient().create(WeatherService.class);

  Call<Weather> call = weatherService.getWeatherData("Ankara",weatherService.API_KEY);

  call.enqueue(new Callback<Weather>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<Weather> call, Response<Weather> response) {

          Log.d("onResponse","I am here");

          tv.setText(response.body().getDescription());
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<Weather> call, Throwable t) {

      }
  });




}
```

What is the problem and how can I solve this?
Thank you guys sincerely

Answer (score 0):

Try with this: add `/` at the end of baseurl.

**Base url:**

```
 String BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/";
```

**Request :**

```
@GET("weather")
//q=CityName &appid =APIKEY
Call<String> getWeatherData(@Query("q") String cityName,@Query("APPID") String apikey);
```

Take response as `String` or `JsonNode` then try to convert your pojo. you will find where is your problem.

Comment: Program type already present: retrofit2.BuiltInConverters$RequesyBodyConverter

Comment: I tried POJO. I have any idea what will I do, I am stack. Your answer is not working

Comment: Hey @sajib. I wanna say thank you for your solutions. I tried all of them but nothing is changed. I looked other retrofit examples, they are same with me. Actually the error is com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex. I tried many solutions as multiDexenable true. But it does not work. My mind is blind now :D